# Where are constant volatile variables stored in c ?

Tags: c, microcontroller

In which section is constant volatile variable stored in c.? In micro-controllers we should put such kind of variables in RAM. Right?

Comment: In Microcontroller, You can see Port Pins are generally defined as the volatile variable. Due to that compiler will not optimize the code & will not replace the value with cached value. So we can make sure that every time it will read the latest updated value from port pins only.

Comment: "A constant volatile variable" is nonsense: Either it's a constant, or it's a variable! What do you intend with using such a construct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `const volatile` variable means that your C program can't legally change it, but something else can. It would be logical to place this variable in RAM, but the compiler won't complain if you tell it (via a linker script or a similar option) to place in ROM. It may also be useful to locate this variable where some memory-mapped device is, e.g. a read-only timer counter register or an ADC output register.

Comment: So if we are assigning constant variables to ROM then compiler will automatically allocate such variables to ROM. right?

Comment: It depends on your compiler and how you use it.

Answer (score 9):

`Volatile` has noting to do with where the variable is stored. It just tells the compiler to read the variable from memory **every time** to avoid any optimization that compiler might perform for that variable.

Answer (score 9):

1. Local variables and function frame - stack
2. Global and static  variables if uninitialized - .bss block start by symbol
3. Global and static variables if initialized - data segment
4. Environment variables and arguments - on top of the stack
5. Dynamic data allocation - heap
6. Const - ROM
7. Volatile - no storage
8. Register - cpu register
9. Const volatile - in the same place as const storage

Answer (score 3):

`const` variables for microcontroller applications are most likely stored in flash **ROM**. The only time they are stored in RAM is when they are evaluated in runtime, such as const parameters to functions. Or when you are doing some debug build executing from RAM.

`volatile` has nothing to do with where variables are stored, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a constant needs to RAM address, it could be stored in ROM, but most likely it will be stored (by expansion) in the (read-only) assembly code, much like for `a += 2`.
That's a fast as it could get for a `volatile`.